# Custom QIcon using QIconEngine and transparency

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qtgui, qicon

I'm trying to implement something like "composed icon" in Qt.

**Target:** I need to dynamicaly set color just for the portion of icon.

**My idea:** Compose this icon by two other. One icon that will be coloured as desired (perhaps by ColorizeEffect) and blend it under second icon that acts as overlay layer.

**Issue:** I tried **QIconEngine** and implementing its **paint** method. ColorizeEffect seems not to be working (even when I try the hack with temporary QLabel for that - when strength is set > 0.0, the QIcon formed by that is empty). But that's not the main problem. The thing is, no matter what I do, I get some default coloured background for this "composed" icon.

[image: Two QToolButtons with QIcons, left icon is simple QIcon, right is my "Composed" icon]

Here is fragment of my code:

```
class QComposedIconEngine: public QIconEngine
{
public:
   QComposedIconEngine();
   ~QComposedIconEngine();
   virtual void paint ( QPainter * painter, const QRect & rect, QIcon::Mode mode, QIcon::State state );
   virtual QIconEngine * clone(void) const;
public:
   QIcon m_qIconA;
   QIcon m_qIconB;
   QColor m_qColor;
};
```

And here is my implementation of paint(...):

```
void CLxQComposedIconEngine::paint ( QPainter * painter, const QRect & rect, QIcon::Mode mode, QIcon::State state )
{
   QBrush brush = painter->background();
   QColor color = brush.color();
   brush.setColor( Qt::transparent );
   painter->setBackground( brush );
   painter->eraseRect( rect );
   painter->setCompositionMode( QPainter::CompositionMode_SourceOver );
   m_qIconA.paint( painter, rect, Qt::AlignCenter, mode, state );
};
```

And here is how I create that "Composed" icon:

```
QComposedIconEngine * qIconEngine = new QComposedIconEngine();
QIcon i1;
QIcon i2;
i1.addPixmap(...);
i2.addPixmap(...);
qIconEngine->m_qIconA = i1;
qIconEngine->m_qIconB = i2;
QIcon i3( qIconEngine );
```

I expect i1 and i3 to look exactly the same. And besides the damn background it really is.
But I need to make it transparent.

(even when I leave my paint(...) method empty, the damn background is there!)

Does anybody know how to make the background transparent?
Thanks.

Comment: Doc of QIconEngine says "use QIconEngineV2". Have you tried that ?

Comment: Of course. No effect. Fortunatelly I solved this problem. It is in the way QIconEngine is called from outside. I'm going to compile the answer by myself... :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved this. The problem was, that the reimplemented **paint(...)** method is almost every time called via **pixmap(...)** method - which can be reimplemented too. If you leave default implementation, this method creates new **QPixmap**, creates **QPainter** on it and calls **paint(...)** witch this painter. But that is the problem - since the created QPixmap contains no alpha channel it cannot be semi-transparent.
So you need to reimplement pixmap(...) method like this:

```
QPixmap CLxQComposedIconEngine::pixmap ( const QSize & size, QIcon::Mode mode, QIcon::State state )
{   
   QImage img( size, QImage::Format_ARGB32 );
   img.fill(qRgba(0,0,0,0));
   QPixmap pix = QPixmap::fromImage(img, Qt::NoFormatConversion );
   {
      QPainter painter ( &pix );
      QRect r( QPoint(0.0,0.0), size );
      this->paint(&painter, r, mode, state);      
   }
   return pix;       
};
```

The key are the first two rows... Without the **img.fill()** it would be not transparent.

Comment: `QPixmap pix(size);
pix.fill(Qt::transparent);`is sufficient, you don't need to make a QImage.